# how to embed online plotly choropleth map link & script into existing Dash code

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have created an online Plotly choropleth map with US map with states getting data from an sqlite database... 
I created an online html file at my plotly cloud account to be able to embed it in my custom Dash webpage that is currently at localhost. I could not find how to embed this online plotly graph into my existing Dash app.layout code so that I show everything in the same web page. Below is the overall code:

1) First i create an online Plotly choropleth map on my Plotly account. This works perfectly.

```
data = [ dict(
        type='choropleth',
        locations = df['code'],
        z = df['total exports'].astype(float),
        locationmode = 'USA-states',

       ................................. Here I truncated the code for the sake of space................................

        py.plot({"data":data, "layout":layout}, filename='US _Social_Sentiment_Map.html')
```

2) Then I retrieved the generated HTML link from my plotly account's embed HTML part for the above map. It looks something like this:

```
<div>
    <a href="https://plot.ly/~USERNAME/2/?share_key=qYb0mASJDFasdnfasdfASD" target="_blank" title="US _Social_Sentiment_Map.html" style="display: block; text-align: center;"><img src="https://plot.ly/~myUser/2.png?share_key=qYb0mASJDFasdnfasdfASD" alt="US _Social_Sentiment_Map.html" style="max-width: 100%;width: 600px;"  width="600" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='https://plot.ly/404.png';" /></a>
    <script data-plotly="sailor77:2" sharekey-plotly="qYb0mASJDFasdnfasdfASD"
 src="https://plot.ly/embed.js" async></script>
</div>
```

3) Then I would like to embed the above Plotly choropleth map link into below python Dash code and publish the map at the resultant website at http://127.0.0.1:8050/. I could not figure out how to embed it despite different trials.  My Dash code (without the above map link) looks like below (source: https://github.com/Sentdex/socialsentiment/blob/master/dash_mess.py )

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([   


        html.Div(className='container-fluid', children=[html.H2('Live Twitter Sentiment', style={'color':"#CECECE"}),
                                                        html.H5('Search:', style={'color':app_colors['text']}),
                                                  dcc.Input(id='sentiment_term', value='twitter', type='text', style={'color':app_colors['someothercolor']}),
                                                  ],
                 style={'width':'98%','margin-left':10,'margin-right':10,'max-width':50000}),



        html.Div(className='row', children=[html.Div(id='related-sentiment', children=html.Button('Loading related terms...', id='related_term_button'), className='col s12 m6 l6', style={"word-wrap":"break-word"}),
                                            html.Div(id='recent-trending', className='col s12 m6 l6', style={"word-wrap":"break-word"})]),

        html.Div(className='row', children=[html.Div(dcc.Graph(id='live-graph', animate=False), className='col s12 m6 l6'),
                                            html.Div(dcc.Graph(id='historical-graph', animate=False), className='col s12 m6 l6')]),

        html.Div(className='row', children=[html.Div(id="recent-tweets-table", className='col s12 m6 l6'),
                                            html.Div(dcc.Graph(id='sentiment-pie', animate=False), className='col s12 m6 l6'),]),


        dcc.Interval(
            id='graph-update',
            interval=1*1000
        ),
        dcc.Interval(
            id='historical-update',
            interval=60*1000
        ),

        dcc.Interval(
            id='related-update',
            interval=30*1000
        ),

        dcc.Interval(
            id='recent-table-update',
            interval=2*1000
        ),

        dcc.Interval(
            id='sentiment-pie-update',
            interval=60*1000
        ),

    ], style={'backgroundColor': app_colors['background'], 'margin-top':'-30px', 'height':'2000px',},
)
```

Thanks for any suggestions or help.

Comment: Suggest you to added those two lines to the end of file: `if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)`: it's a part of each Dash application. Maybe it helps you in your way to find a problem

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved how to add a plotly choropleth_map in my Dash code. Assuming you have installed the latest Dash releases, I had to make 3 changes to make it work.

First is to add the choropleth_map id under my 'app.layout = html.Div([  ' section as below.

```
html.Div(className='row', children= [html.Div(dcc.Graph(id='choropleth_map', style={"height": "100%", "width": "100%"}, config=dict(displayModeBar=True)), className='col s12 m6 l6'),
html.Div(dcc.Graph(id='sentiment-pie', animate=False), className='col s12 m6 l6')]),
```

Secondly, add the interval value so that the map is updated. This is under the 'app.layout' as well.

```
dcc.Interval(
    id='choropleth_map-update',
    interval=10*1000, n_intervals=0
),
```

Third, add below like section to call back the initial Dash declarations.

```
@app.callback(Output("choropleth_map", "figure"),
             [Input('input-div', 'children'),
                 #Input(component_id='sentiment_term', component_property='value'),
              Input('choropleth_map-update', 'n_intervals')]) 
def map_callback(sentiment_term, n_intervals):
    #df = pd.read_csv(r'LOCAL PATH\mySourceFile.csv')  #if you use a local CSV file
    sql_term = "SELECT XXXX"   # if you read from a database
    df = pd.read_sql(sql_term, conn)
    return choropleth_map(df, sentiment_term)
```

This worked for me well... Hope you can re-apply.